# Being prompted for a login when I shouldnt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

When I attempt to go to a webpage I am getting this message:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this
>   page due to invalid authentication headers.

As you can see from this picture:

[image]

This is confusing considering that I am going directly to this page from my logon screen and I'm not getting a prompt. I can go to any other portion of the site without being prompted also.

Here is the code I am using to link to this screen:

```
@using SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService

<br />
<br />
<table>

  @if (ViewData["CustomerData"] != null) { 
    foreach (var usr in (IEnumerable<CustomerData>) ViewData["CustomerData"])
    {
      <tr>

        <td>
          <a href="/Customer/ShowCustomer/@usr.AccountId/">View</a>
        </td>

        <td>
          @usr.Branch-@usr.AccountNumber
        </td>

        <td>
          @usr.Name
        </td>

        <td>
          @usr.DeliveryStreet
        </td>

      </tr>
    }
  }

</table>
<br />
```

Does it have something to do with it being a link? If so, how do I get around this?

**UPDATE #1**

This is the action that is being called:

```
public ViewResult ShowCustomer(string id)
{
  var corpid = MiscClasses.TokenIdCookie.GetTokenIdCookie();
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.AppendLine("SuburbanCustPortal,Controllers.CustomerController.ExistingAccounts");
  sb.AppendLine(string.Format("corpid: {0}", corpid));
  sb.AppendLine(string.Format("accountid (id): {0}", id));
  Logging.LogInfo(sb.ToString(), _asName);

  var cr = new CustomerRequest();
  cr.CompanyId = corpid;
  cr.Account = id;

  return View("AccountScreen", _client.GetCustomerByGuid(cr));
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

I am using the following authentication:

[image]

Comment: Need the Action that you are linking to and the markup for the page that action returns...

Comment: What authentication options have you configured in IIS?

Comment: Enable Anonymous authentication on IIS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems your IIS requires you to be authenticated via Basic authentication challenge/response. Anonymous access is disabled hence authentication dialog appears.

Enable **anonymous authentication** and you should be good to go.

The usual authentication methods for everyday Asp.net applications (including MVC ones) that should be enabled are:

- Anonymous and
- Forms

All others depend on your application's specific requirements and/or environment (i.e. domain configuration).